# Python: Trouble getting image to download/save to file

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and seem to be having trouble getting an image to download and save to a file. I was wondering if someone could point out my error. I have tried two methods in various ways to no avail. Here is my code below:

```
# Ask user to enter URL
url= http://hosted.ap.org/dynamic/stories/A/AF_PISTORIUS_TRIAL?SITE=AP&SECTION=HOME&TEMPLATE=DEFAULT&CTIME=2014-04-15-15-48-52

timestamp = datetime.date.today()  

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
#soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

# ap
links = soup.find("td", {'class': 'ap-mediabox-td'}).find_all('img', src=True)
for link in links:
    imgfile = open('%s.jpg' % timestamp, "wb")
    link = link["src"].split("src=")[-1]
    imgurl = "http://hosted.ap.org/dynamic/files" + link
    download_img = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl).read()
    #download_img = requests.get(imgurl, stream=True)
    #imgfile.write(download_img.content)
    imgfile.write(download_img)
    imgfile.close() 

    # link outputs: /photos/F/f5cc6144-d991-4e28-b5e6-acc0badcea56-small.jpg
    # imgurl outputs: http://hosted.ap.org/dynamic/files/photos/F/f5cc6144-d991-4e28-b5e6-acc0badcea56-small.jpg
```

I receive no console error, just an empty picture file.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path of the image can be obtained as simply as by doing:

```
link = link["src"]
```

Your statement:

```
link = link["src"].split("src=")[-1]
```

is excessive. Replace it with above and you should get the image file created. When I tried it out, I could get the image file to be created. However, I was not able to view the image. It said, the image was corrupted.

I have had success in the past doing the same task using python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library using this code snippet:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open('photo.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content():
                    f.write(chunk)
            f.close()
```

`url` in the snippet above would be your `imgurl` computed with the changes I suggested at the beginning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. I tried using requests previously. Still getting the image corrupted result. Any idea what may be causing this?